# Fix NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, repair

Okay, so i was about to resize one of my NTFS partitions but suddenly the partition tool showed me an error and it crashed, so i was no longer able to use my partition - even when i tried mounting it under linux it showed me error.

I installed active partition recovery, and using it i can see all my files on that partition - it's all there, nothing's been removed. I just need somehow to fix the partition so it can be usable again. Can you tell me how, or using with which tool/software ?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe post the exact error messages you're getting?

Comment: kbyrd: when i try to browse it with windows explorer i get error "D:\ is not accessible, the file or directory is corrupted or unreadable".

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) - it's very good at this kind of thing.  It's also included on the [Knoppix](http://www.knoppix.net/) Live CD and some other Linux distributions, so you can boot from that and run TestDisk on the drive/partition you need to recover.

Comment: +1 for testdisk - used it just yesterday when I accidentally quick formatted a partitioned drive: quick, easy, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

For there linux there should be a tool to fix a ntfs called ntfsfix. But maybe you can just launch microsoft scandisk on it following this tutorial: [how to perform scandisk in windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156571/en-us?fr=1).